# Handle prompt window closing confirmation [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, onbeforeunload

I know this is a very simple question but even of being a simple question I yet don't find answers to it:

How do i handle if a user confirms to close the page and execute an action in that moment

here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
    // handle if user confirms to close window
    // if so then call a function (ex, do something)
});
```

HOW DO I ACHIEVE THIS?

IMPORTANT:

I want to make an API call to alter server side data when the user closes the window, what is more suitable to achieve such goal based on the base question?

Comment: if the page hasn't gets loaded (ie, beforeload), then will other JavaScript code will be loaded?

Comment: @ProClasic No, the page doesn't execute code before loading the page

Comment: then how will you interact with the api.....i think you can make your custom beforeload page and then load the remaining part.

Comment: @ProClasic I still dont understand your idea, I dont know what beforeload is used for, I knew that beforeunload is handled whenever the user closes the page, so its there where I want to execute the code which calls the API (only when the user closes the window)

Comment: oh i am really sorry i misread it as 'beforload' instead of 'beforeunload'....my bad